# Javascript - checking if frame is empty

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I tried to check if the frame "content1" and "content3" are empty or not and then resizing them.

But the size just changes every loop

```
window.setInterval(function () {
check();
}, 50);

function check() {

    var content1 = document.getElementsByName("content")[0].contentDocument.body;
    var content3 = document.getElementsByName("content3")[0].contentDocument.body;

    if (isEmpty(content3)) {
        if (isEmpty(content1)) setProperties("0px, *, 0px");
        else setProperties("35%, *, 0px");
    } else setProperties("25%, 40%, 35%");

    window.localStorage.clear();
}

function isEmpty(e) {
    return (e.offsetWidth != 0);
}

function setProperties(value) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")[1].cols = value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecytve7w/8/

Comment: [Here is a version of the jsfiddle that doesn't log errors because it checks the return value of all the DOM calls.](https://jsfiddle.net/6vnna01u/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, that error means what it says: `e` is `null`, so `e.offsetWidth` will throw the exception. Just check `e` also:

```
return !!(e && (e.offsetWidth != 0 || e.innerHTML != "\n"));
```

The `!!` makes it such that the function always returns a boolean `true` or `false` result, which isn't necessary but I like to do that with `isFoo()` functions just to be nice.

Why would `e` be null? In this case it'd be because the code didn't find either the "content" or "content3" elements on the page.

Comment: @error404username_not_found can you update your question with a link to the actual fiddle? The code here and the code in the linked fiddle are different. You won't get that error if you put it inside `isEmpty()` with `e` declared as the parameter.